# Can code in a Javascript file know its own domain/URL

Tags: javascript

If I have a site, example.com, and a page on that site references a Javascript at subdomain.example.com/serveAd.js -- is there a way from within serveAd.js to know its own URL, or the domain from which it was downloaded?

(The JS can certainly know all about the page that called it. I want to know if the JS knows about its own origin.)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019112/getting-url-of-executing-javascript-file-ie6-7-problem-mostly

Comment: Does the JS know its own *file name*?

Comment: Indeed, it's addressed similarly in other places. And the answers are similar to below, which are good ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you were using jquery, you could get the full url with this kind of thing:

```
var fullJsUrl= $('script[src$=serveAd.js]').attr('src');
```

If not using jquery, it may take more work, but you get the idea ;)

Comment: Not sure if this is due to the changes in jquery since this question, but now this only works for me with $('script[src$="serveAd.js"]').attr('src'); // quotes around the file name

Comment: Without jquery `document.querySelector('script[src$="serveAd.js"]).src`

Comment: @gman good response but there's a typo. Should be `document.querySelector('script[src$="serveAd.js"]').src` with the closing single quote

Comment: This will find the first script file which name ends with "serveAd.js". So this will fail if there is multiple scripts like that (such as a "dont-serveAd.js" before "serveAd.js"). It will also fail if the script has been renamed for some reason. (But this name was given in the question, so not a problem in this case.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure, as the script is parsed that the last `<script>` node available in the DOM will be the one being parsed.

Try this in an external JS to see:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
alert(lastScript.src);
```

Comment: Not if the script file was loaded using createElement/appendChild, then it could be anywhere in the DOM (depending on where you appended it to).

Comment: This will fail if the script is loaded async (which is becoming more popular).