# Read variables in .JS HTML include

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting URL of executing JavaScript file (IE6-7 problem mostly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019112/getting-url-of-executing-javascript-file-ie6-7-problem-mostly)

Hi my page has this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pixel.js?name=Test&age=21"></script>
```

I need pixel.js to access the vairables name and age, how is this possible? I tried using address bar variable (get POST data) method but it comes out undefined as I imagine this isn't technically in the address bar...

Thanks
Craig

Comment: I agree this is a dup, but that question doesn't have a good answer (probably because there really isn't one).

Comment: If you explain what you want to do overall, there's almost certainly a better, reliable way to do what you're doing.

Comment: @Pointy If the other question is definitely a dupe but with no good answers, then we should work on improving the answers to that one (even if the definitive answer is "there is no solution").

Comment: @Blowski fair enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this as long as pixel.js is a static file. If you want to do something like this you have to use some server handler to serve javascript files and read query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pass variables from your HTML page to JavaScript or what are you doing?

IF you reallt need to do that check this tutorial:
http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

I actually found a similar discussion and swiped user378221's answer: 
[Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)

I would recommend declaring your variables ina  sperate script tag and then including the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it by finding the script tag with your filename and then parsing the `src` attribute... something like this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    scriptTest = /^pixel\.js/,
    pixelScript, params,
    getScriptParams = function(scriptSrc){
        var qSplit = scriptSrc.split('?'),
            aSplit = qSplit[1].split('&'),
            retVals = {}, pSplit;

        for (var i = 0, il = aSplit.length; i < il; i++) {
            pSplit = aSplit[i].split('=');
            retVals[pSplit[0]] = pSplit.length > 1 ? pSplit[1] : null;
        }

        return retVals;
    };

for (var i = 0, il = scripts.length; i < il; i++) {
    if (scriptTest.test(scripts[i].src)) {
        pixelScript = scripts[i];
    }
}

params = getScriptParams(pixelScript.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Not tested

Just put an ID on the script element and then grab it from the included script (they exist on the same DOM, so it should work)

HTML:

```
<script id="blah" type="text/javascript" src="foo.js?key=value" />
```

foo.js:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('blah').src);​
```

​